# FTP not listing directory NcFTP PASV

Tags: ftp, passive

I am attempting to setup Multicraft on my server, all is running smoothly however the FTP won't allow anyone to connect from a remote FTP client, where net2ftp will work smoothly from a remote location.

I have included the transcript from my FTP client, Transmit below to give you an idea of what's going on.

I have disabled iptables as well, and still no luck either way.

```
Transmit 4.1.7 (x86_64) Session Transcript [Version 10.8.2 (Build 12C54)] (21/10/12 11:23 PM)
LibNcFTP 3.2.3 (July 23, 2009) compiled for UNIX
220: Multicraft 1.7.1 FTP server
Connected to ateam.bn-mc.net.
Cmd: USER jacob.9
331: Username ok, send password.
Cmd: PASS xxxxxxxx
230: Login successful
Cmd: TYPE A
200: Type set to: ASCII.
Logged in to ateam.bn-mc.net as jacob.9.
Cmd: SYST
215: UNIX Type: L8
Cmd: FEAT
211: Features supported:
      EPRT
      EPSV
      MDTM
      MLSD
      MLST type*;perm*;size*;modify*;unique*;unix.mode;unix.uid;unix.gid;
      REST STREAM
      SIZE
      TVFS
      UTF8
     End FEAT.
Cmd: OPTS UTF8 ON
200: OK
Cmd: PWD
257: "/" is the current directory.
Cmd: PASV
Could not read reply from control connection -- timed out. (SReadline 1)
```

Comment: What does _your local_ firewall look like?

Comment: Local firewall is fine, as I replicated it on a local PE 1850 server I have here at home and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you mention the local firewall is fine, but if you do not have the nf_conntrack_ftp module loaded, PASV mode won't work right.